# How can I get data for select box and set the data while using searching?

Tags: html, jquery, spring, drop-down-menu

```
         <div>
            <label for="sort">sort</label>
            <select name="sort" id="sort" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="label">label</label>
            <select name="label" id="label" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="label1">label1</option>
                <option value="label2">label2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

There is a search function, so when I choose the sort and label select box then click the search button, it will sort data. But the selected value is not set in the select box.

How can I solve this? Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. What jQuery did you try?

Comment: *But selected value is not setted in the select box* - how are you sorting?  Are you making an ajax call? a full POST? a redirect?  Depends on how your framework (sping?) handles re-setting inputs after a POST, so you may need some code on save/load to save/load the value.

Answer (score 0):

Add any event to get the selected dropdown value. Below, I have added a select `change` event.

```js
$("#label").on("change", function(){
  //get the data using the above ID's
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]; //example array
  
  //appending to the new Select #newData
  var htmlContent = "";
  htmlContent = "<option value=''></option>";
  $.each( cars, function( i, val ) {
    $( "#" + val ).text( "Mine is " + val + "." );
    htmlContent += "<option value= "+val+">"+val+"</option>";
  });
  $("#newData").append(htmlContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
            <label for="sort">sort</label>
            <select name="sort" id="sort" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="label">label</label>
            <select name="label" id="label" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="label1">label1</option>
                <option value="label2">label2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        
        <div>
            <label for="newData">New Data</label>
            <select name="newData" id="newData" class="form-control">
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: I learned from your comment that I have to use change event. But I want to set the value which I selected in the select box, not the alert function.

Comment: Where do you need to set the value?

Comment: For example, there is a merchandise list and I can search a product with a search box. If I want to sort them with id, I can click select box and click the id ascending or id descending, and  click the button named "search". Then it will show me the list that sorted by select box value. But it does not maintain the value in the select box. Do you understand...?

Comment: You want the second select dropdown with the dynamic option from the result of first dropdown am I right?

Comment: um.. I do not know dynamic option exactly, but I can say that there are separate select boxes.

Comment: @jjungdev Check the updated answer and let me know